# REST - Jersey - Spring - File Download

Tags: spring, rest, file, download, jersey

I'm having a REST API (POST Method) that produces MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM and the response header is also set with the following code.

```
@Path("/file")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getFile() throws IOException {
```

.
.
.

```
ResponseBuilder respBuilder = Response.ok((Object) file);
respBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\";");
return respBuilder.build();
```

However when I call this API from Postman or  My App, This does not download a file, Rather it gives response in body with content and Response code 200.

Not sure what is wrong here! Am i supposed to do any additional configuration in Spring / WEB Server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an InputStream as the response body.
Try this:

```
InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(file)
ResponseBuilder respBuilder = Response.ok(targetStream);
respBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\";");
return respBuilder.build();
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but this did not help.